# Performance Tuning Angularjs ng-repeat for large lists

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an angularjs directive I have written that acts like a form select component. It has a search field to search through the choices. When you click on a choice it removes the choice from the list of choices and displays it, above the search field, as a selection. When you click on a selection it removes it from the selections, above the search field, and places it back in the choices list.

I have done a lot of research on ng-repeat and it's potential performance issues, which I have seen. In my current iteration I am using bindonce, limitTo and track by, and an infinite scroll. On my laptop this directive is very fast, on iPhone 5, still very fast, on iPhone 4 pretty fast and on iPhone 3 junk. On iPhone 3 the text search filtering through the choices is fast, but the selecting a choice or selection is where it is slow.

Here is the ng-repeat I am using for choices:

```
<a bindonce refresh-on="'refreshSelect'" ng-repeat="choice in choices | filter:{name: searchFilter.name, selected: false}:strict | orderBy:'name' | limitTo: limitNumberOfChoices track by choice.id" ng-click="addToSelections(choice)">
    <div class="well well-sm" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
        <strong>
            <span bo-bind="choice.name"></span> 
            <span class="badge" ng-show="choice.badgeValue" bo-bind="choice.badgeValue"></span>
        </strong>
    </div>
</a>
```

Here is the ng-repeat I am using for selections:

```
<a bindonce refresh-on="'refreshSelect'" ng-repeat="selection in selections | orderBy:'name' track by selection.id" ng-click="removeFromSelections(selection)">
    <div class="well well-sm" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <strong>
            <span bo-bind="selection.name"></span> 
            <span class="badge" ng-show="selection.badgeValue" bo-bind="selection.badgeValue"></span>
        </strong>
    </div>
</a>
```

A plunker of my directive is at http://plnkr.co/edit/ziQstcBHXsMyIPNnetur?p=preview

Choices are below the input field. Selections are above the input field. You can scroll through the choices. infiniteScroll will fire when you have scrolled 75% down the list of choices. This will add 50 to the limitTo in ng-repeat. The choices array is 10000 items large.

I need suggestions on how to speed this directive up. Unfortunately we have a large number of iPhone 3s, getting rid of them is not an option. I am probably doing something real simple that is slowing it down.

Thanks in advance

Warren

#### UPDATED

I took off the orderBy on the ng-repeat for the choices list. Choices is the large list with 10000 records. This increased the speed a bit but still slow on iPhone 3.

Comment: It's a custom on SO to put some of the relevant code in your question, too. Also, iphone 3g was released in '08, in mobile land that is pretty much ancient. Can you start displaying your list of choices after at least three or four characters have been entered in the search field, or limit to like, 100 results? Displaying 10000's of items doesn't make much sense anyway. Who's going to scroll down the whole list instead of keep typing?

Comment: Jorg, as stated in post, getting rid of iPhone 3s not an option. Not sure what code is relevant, hence the plunker. Not sure what you mean by limit to 100 results after typing 3 characters. Are you talking about some sort of server side loading of choices based on search input ?

Comment: I didn't mean getting rid of the older model, I ment you're stuck with old tech...Maybe I misunderstood. Usually it's not storing an array of choices that's slow, it's displaying them. So, don't display all the choices. I can't actually get your plunkr to do anything.

Comment: Jorg, bummer about plunker not working, works for me in chrome and safari, oh well. I placed the ng-repeat code in the original post. I am using ng-repeat limitTo initially set to 50 and an infinite scroll that adds 50 to limitTo as you scroll down the choices. Just seems to be slow when adding a choice from the choices array to the selections array. I don't actually remove the choice from the choices array, I just set the property named "selected" to true and filter by it. I do add and remove choice objects from the selections array though.